# How do you associate an image lambda with CloudFront distribution via terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am migrating some manually created resources in AWS into terraform.

Currently, I have the a terraform script which creates the necessary lambda, role and permissions for the lambda to write logs into CloudWatch which looks like this:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
  name = "${var.brand}-oauth-lambda-role"
  inline_policy {
    name = "Allow-CloudWatch-Logs"
    policy = jsonencode({
      Version = "2012-10-17",
      Statement = [
        {
           Effect = "Allow",
           Action = [ "logs:CreateLogGroup", "logs:CreateLogStream", "logs:PutLogEvents" ],
           Resource = [ "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*" ]
         }
       ]
     })
    }
    
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
         Effect = "Allow",
         Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
         Principal = {
           "Service": [
              "lambda.amazonaws.com",
              "edgelambda.amazonaws.com"
           ]
         },
       }
     ]
  })
}
    
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  function_name = "${var.brand}-oauth-lambda"
  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
  architectures = [ "x86_64" ]
  package_type = "Image"
  image_uri = "xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/yyy@sha256:zzz"
  runtime = "nodejs18.x"
}
```

This successfully creates all resources. However, this lambda is supposed to be executed as CloudFront Lambda@Edge. Normally, from the AWS UI console you can use the `Add trigger` button and point it towards the CF distribution. However I can't seem to find how this is done with terraform. Is this supported or do you need to go about it in a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use the [`lambda_function_association` configuration block](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_distribution#lambda-function-association). Based on the example from the documentation, you would need to use something like the following:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "example" {
  # ... other configuration ...

  # lambda_function_association is also supported by default_cache_behavior
  ordered_cache_behavior {
    # ... other configuration ...

    lambda_function_association {
      event_type   = "viewer-request" # or one of the other supported event types
      lambda_arn   = aws_lambda_function.lambda.qualified_arn
      include_body = false
    }
  }
}
```

I would also expect you will need to use `aws_lambda_permission` resource:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "cloudfront" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda.function_name
  principal     = "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_cloudfront_distribution.example.arn
}
```

EDIT: Using Lambda functions with CloudFront requires using Lambda versions, i.e., a qualified ARN. For this to work, the version has to be published, which is achieved by adding the [`publish = true`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#publish) to the Lambda function resource:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  function_name = "${var.brand}-oauth-lambda"
  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
  architectures = [ "x86_64" ]
  package_type = "Image"
  image_uri = "xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/yyy@sha256:zzz"
  runtime = "nodejs18.x"
  publish = true
}
```

This will then provide the required qualified ARN. More information from the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-how-it-works.html):

> [...] **Save and publish a numbered version of the function.** [...]

Comment: Thanks for giving the snippet! I believe this is the right answer. However I'm getting `Error: creating CloudFront Distribution: InvalidLambdaFunctionAssociation: The function ARN must reference a specific function version. (The ARN must end with the version number.) ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xyz:function:oauth-lambda:$LATEST
status code: 400`. Unsure what more is missing here. I've added the `lambda_function_association` into the `distribution` and the `lambda:InvokeFunction` permission.

Comment: What about `aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn` instead of `aws_lambda_function.lambda.qualified_arn`?

Comment: I'm getting the same error unfortunately. After going through the documentation it looks like the problem is that the `lambda_function_association` expects the function to be `Lambda@Edge` whereas I have a Lambda. In the GUI you would go to the lambda and select `Actions -> Deploy as Lambda@Edge` which does the linking.

Comment: I think you actually need to set `publish = true` for your Lambda function because it seems that you need a versioned Lambda function for associating it with CloudFront.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the problem. Lol however it looks like AWS DOES NOT support `container images` for Lamdba@edges. I will mark your answer as the accepted since it looks like it is the right answer to the `zip` package type.